# I am having trouble with basic Python syntax

Tags: python

I am just learning Python and coding in general, and I assume this is a pretty noobie question.

```
def get_age_difference(first, second):
    text = 'The age difference is '
    number = abs(int('%04d' % (first)) - int('%04d' % (second)))
    return text, number

print(get_age_difference(2001, 2018))
```

I get
`('The age difference is ', 17)`

I want to get
`The age difference is 17`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can include `text_number = text + str(number)` and then `return text_number`, You are returning two separate variables with your current code, but your goal is to return a string, so you have to include code that transforms the two separate variables into one variable that is a combined string rather than two separate variables.

Comment: Why don't you just substract the two using `abs()` and use `str()` on it. The return value is a tuple and not a string. `return text+str(abs(first-second))`

Comment: a function named `get_age_difference` should probably just return the difference.  the text comment should be added by the caller.   Just return the numeric result from your function, then format and add commentary in your print statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a tuple containing two values. You can use tuple unpacking to assign each of these values to separate variables. Noticed that I've removed the trailing space in the text - spacing should be decided by the thing that does the diplay.

```
def get_age_difference(first, second):
    text = 'The age difference is'
    number = abs(int('%04d' % (first)) - int('%04d' % (second)))
    return text, number

description, difference = get_age_difference(2001, 2018)
```

Now you have choices. Here are examples using f-strings and additional arguments to print.

```
print(f"{description} {difference}")
print(description, difference)
```

Alternately, you can expand an iterable such as a tuple into a function. Your two values could become to arguments to print.

```
print(*get_age_difference(2001, 2018))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use f strings:

```
def get_age_difference(first, second):
    num = abs(int('%04d' % (first)) - int('%04d' % (second)))
    result = f'The age difference is {num}'
    return result
print(get_age_difference(2001, 2018))
```

Or just use +

```
def get_age_difference(first, second):
    text = 'The age difference is '
    number = str(abs(int('%04d' % (first)) - int('%04d' % (second))))
    return text + number

print(get_age_difference(2001, 2018))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use formatted string;

```
def get_age_difference(first, second):
    num = abs(int('%04d' % (first)) - int('%04d' % (second)))
    result = f'The age difference is {num}'
    
    return result

print(get_age_difference(2001, 2018))
```

Comment: formatted string in python helps to use the variables inside a string. As you can see in my answer, i am able to plug in the value of 'num' inside the string 'result'

Answer (score 0):

You are returning two numbers which will be printed as a `tuple`. Instead concatenate the string in this way

```
def get_age_difference(first, second):
    text = 'The age difference is '
    number = str(abs(int('%04d' % (first)) - int('%04d' % (second))))
    return text+ number

print(get_age_difference(2001, 2018))
```

This will print the required output

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
def get_age_difference(first, second):
   number = abs(int('%04d' % (first)) - int('%04d' % (second)))
   result = 'The age difference is {}'.format(number)
   return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_age_difference(first, second):
    text = 'The age difference is '
    number = abs(int('%04d' % (first)) - int('%04d' % (second)))
    print(text,number)

get_age_difference(2001, 2018)
```

you can try the method as this.